# Is there a way in Golang to inverse a boolean

Tags: go

is there short version in Go to reverse a boolean?

instead of:

```
b := true

if b {
    b = false
} else {
    b = true
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/SgQ1cN5qIAZ is this your desired behavior?

Comment: `b = !b` did you try this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, just do `b = !b`. Here is a [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/3uFG-blDkX6) where you can see it in action.